# Image is displayed locally with no problem, but not always after deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, heroku-cli

Hello I have a problem with showing pictures on HEROKU. The funny thing is, however, that the images are not displayed everywhere, but only in a few places. And I find it even stranger that it happens in the same component where the images are loaded. The component is a menu which is represented on every page. If I navigate to another page, the image disappears. It is only visible on the main page '/'.

```
import LogoBild from "../images/earth-globe.png";
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The image is not displayed on a subpage '/Profile'

[image]

Comment: I assume the final `src` is the same everywhere? Is you site live so we can take a look?

Comment: Yes it is. No - the application is available privately. But I can give or write any information

Comment: By `locally` do you mean in the development server or after the build?

Comment: On the development server.

Comment: If I call up the backend, which is on Heroku, in the frontend on my local computer, I get all the images in no time. If I open the frontend via Heroku, I don't see all of them